# Django using get_user_model vs settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: python, django

Reading the Django Documentation:

**get_user_model()**

> Instead of referring to User directly, you should reference the user
>   model using django.contrib.auth.get_user_model(). This method will
>   return the currently active User model – the custom User model if one
>   is specified, or User otherwise.
>
> When you define a foreign key or many-to-many relations to the User
>   model, you should specify the custom model using the AUTH_USER_MODEL
>   setting.

I'm confused with the above text. Should I be doing this:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

or this...

```
author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())
```

Both seem to work.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` will delay the retrieval of the actual model class until all apps are loaded. `get_user_model` will attempt to retrieve the model class at the moment your app is imported the first time.

`get_user_model` cannot guarantee that the `User` model is already loaded into the app cache. It might work in your specific setup, but it is a hit-and-miss scenario. If you change some settings (e.g. the order of `INSTALLED_APPS`) it might very well break the import and you will have to spend additional time debugging.

`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` will pass a string as the foreign key model, and if the retrieval of the model class fails at the time this foreign key is imported, the retrieval will be delayed until all model classes are loaded into the cache.

Comment: Concretely, you can run into circular import issues with models.ForeignKey(get_user_model())

Comment: [This section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) says "Generally speaking, you should reference the User model with the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting in code that is executed at import time. `get_user_model()` only works once Django has imported all models."

Comment: So concretely, in functions (views, model/serializer/form methods), use `get_user_model()`, for class attributes use `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Answer (score 85):

### New since Django 1.11.

Since Django 1.11 you can use [`get_user_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) in both cases! So if you don't want to bother about it further, just take it.

"in both cases" means: if you need the user model for accessing its attributes, as well as if you want to define a ForeignKey/ManyToMany-relation.

From [the changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#django-contrib-auth):

> get_user_model() can now be called at import time, even in modules that define models.

so... is there still a reason to use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`? Well, the docs still recommend the `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` (which is a string) for defining relations, but without giving an explicit reason. Might be beneficial for performance, but doesn't seem to matter much.

### Code example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
...
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        null=True, # explicitly set null, since it's required in django 2.x. - otherwise migrations will be incompatible later!
        ...
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `get_user_model()` can be called at import time; however, Django still advises that users define foreign-key and many-to-many relations using [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#get_user_model)

Comment: thank you for pointing out this recommendation, somehow I overlooked it when writing the reply, but now I found it. I tried to integrate this into the answer (still favouring `get_user_model`, especially for readers who are confused about the distinction)

Answer (score 17):

Since Django 1.11, `get_user_model()` actually uses `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`:

```
def get_user_model():
    """
    Return the User model that is active in this project.
    """
    try:
        return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
    except ValueError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'app_label.model_name'")
    except LookupError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
        )
```

Answer (score 14):

`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` returns a string (the location of the User model) e.g. `user_accounts.User`.

`get_user_model()` returns the ACTUAL model class, not a string.

So in cases where you need the User model, use `get_user_model()`. If you need it's location (`module.model` as a string), use the `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by it's location? The app that it belongs or the user that it belongs?

Comment: By location I mean it's path

Answer (score 1):

as i read from book "Two Scoops of Django 3.x"
Using get_user_model():

> This is bad, as it tends to create import loops.

bad example:
owner = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model()) -> BAD DONT DO IT

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`get_user_model()` and `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` are both approaches used in Django to reference the user model when creating relationships between models. However, they serve slightly different purposes and have different use cases.

1. **`get_user_model()`**:

   `get_user_model()` is a function provided by `django.contrib.auth` that returns the user model that is currently active in the project. This function is useful when defining foreign keys or relationships to the user model within your application's models. It ensures that you're always referencing the correct user model, even if you change the user model in your project's settings.

   Here's how you would use `get_user_model()` in your models:

   ```py
   from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

   class SomeModel(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ```
2. **`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`**:

   `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is a string that represents the user model. It is used in situations where you need to reference the user model outside of model definitions, such as in migrations or when creating custom user-related logic.

   For example, if you're creating a custom user manager, you might use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`:

   ```py
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

   class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
       def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
           if not email:
               raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
           email = self.normalize_email(email)
           user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
           user.set_password(password)
           user.save(using=self._db)
           return user

   class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
       email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
       # ...

       objects = CustomUserManager()
   ```

For further Info: [Django customizing auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/)

Answer (score -12):

A way to fallback to the default user model if AUTH_USER_MODEL is not set:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

USER_MODEL = getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', User)
```

Comment: `AUTH_USER_MODEL` already has a default, so it will always be set.

Comment: settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is also a string and your fallback `User` is a model