# Check if a record from one model exists in a list with records from another model in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two simple models defined in Django... one contains album names, and another one that links albums and users.

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UserAlbum
    category = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

In my view I get the list of all albums, and I check which albums the user owns:

```
albums = Album.objects.order_by('name')
my_albums = UserAlbum.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
```

This all works well. However, I now need to display the list with albums online, and a little icon should appear if a user owns an album. I'm not sure how to do this. This is what I have:

```
<ul>
{% for info in albums %}
<li>{{ info.name %} {% if SOME_CONDITION %} <span class="owner"></span>{% endif %}</li>
{% endif %}
```

I am not sure how to formulate SOME_CONDITION. It should basically say: if this album id is also in the my_albums list. But how can I do this?

Comment: the the objects in my_album list are of the model UserAlbum and the objets in albums list is of the model Album. Their ids won't ever match :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need the `UserAlbum` model, unless you want to attach extra fields to the m2m relation. Instead just use a ManyToManyField.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Then you can test for membership in `Album().users.all()` in your template.

```
{% for album in albums %}
<li>{{ album.name }}
  {% if request.user in album.users.all %}
    <span class="owner"></span>
  {% endif %}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

If you have some plan with the UserAlbum model, [you can use it as a intermediate model.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserAlbum')
```

Comment: [get_user_model should be used instead of settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629705/django-using-get-user-model-vs-settings-auth-user-model)

Comment: This is really great, thanks! I didn't know this is how it should be done, still learning Django. I'll change my code accordingly.