# Why we use get user model in the forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Hello guys I want to ask that why we use get user model, can anyone please explain me what is the purpose of it.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta():
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629705/django-using-get-user-model-vs-settings-auth-user-model

Answer (score 1):

We have 3 valid ways to work with User model: directly with `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`, `from django.conf import settings` and `models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,` and last,perhaps the best `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model`. Why the last one? Due to cleaner approach. It return currently active User model (custom or else User).